# looking for a sorting algorithm that can sort 1-100 using the least amount of statements

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

As the title says, I am looking for a sorting algorithm that can sort the numbers between 1 and 100 using the least amount of statements in only one method which is the main.
Here's an example to give you an idea on how I can check it(using a counter)

```
class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args) {   

  //declaration
  int count = 0,inner, outer, temp, h = 1; count++;
  int [] array = {100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,}; count++;
  System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(array)); count++;


  //start of the sort
  while (h <= array.length / 3) //start of while loop 1
    {
    h = h * 3 + 1; count++;
    }count++; //end of while loop 1
    while (h > 0) //start of while loop 2
    {
        for (outer = h; outer < array.length; outer++) //start of for loop
        {
            temp = array[outer]; count++;
            inner = outer;count++;

            while (inner > h - 1 && array[inner - h] >= temp) //start of while loop 3
            {
                array[inner] = array[inner - h]; count++;
                inner -= h; count++;
            }count++; //end of for loop 3
            array[inner] = temp; count++;
        }count++; //end of for loop
        //equation to count for
        count = count + array.length-h+1 + array.length - h +1 -1;
        h = (h - 1) / 3; count++;
    }count++; //end of while loop 2
    System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.toString(array) + "\n" + "Counter = " + count);
}
```

}

Comment: Arrays.sort(array);

Comment: why would you care about the number of statements

Comment: Also, is `h>0` a statement which is evaluated each loop? Isn't `count++` also a statement, so maybe you should use count += 2; one for the count and one for the statement it is counting.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I was just baffled when I tried it on bubble sort vs merge sort. Bubble sort had a lower count. So I am curious if anybody can come up with a better sorting method for that range of numbers

Comment: @matt no, count++ is not counted

Comment: I can't quite comprehend how you can consider number of statements a measurement of performance

Comment: Perhaps you can motivate someone at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, although they usually count in bytes, not statements. But I'm sure you'll finded golfed sorting algorthms somewhere over there ;)

Comment: merge sort should have a much lower count than bubble sort using this metric (number of statement executions, not number of statements).  There was some problem with your bubble sort vs merge sort test.

Comment: [`Counting sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: Fastest for this case is to declare the output `oarray[100]` and make one pass assigning each value to its place in the output. `v = array[i]; oarray[v-1] = v;`

Answer (score 0):

The fastest algorithm with example would be quicksort, also as you are asking i believe this would also take the least amount of statments. Below you can find a link and also description of how it works.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/